# creating thumbnail from a pdf in coldfusion cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, pdf-generation

I'm trying to create a thumbnail from a pdf in coldfusion, but no thumbnail gets created and no exception is thrown.
(coldfusion 9)
my code:

```
var source = "A:\testfolder\test.pdf";
var destination = "A:\testfolder\";

createImageFromPdf(source, destination);
```

createImageFromPdf function:

```
public void function createImageFromPdf(required string source, required string destination,
                                             numeric pages = 1, string resolution = "low",
                                             numeric scale = 100, boolean overwrite = true){

        var pdf = new pdf();
            pdf.setSource(arguments.source);
            pdf.thumbnail(pages = arguments.pages, resolution = arguments.resolution,
                          scale = arguments.scale, overwrite = arguments.overwrite);


}
```

After running this code, i don't receive errors or exceptions, but no image was generated in A:\testfolder\

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but can't find it.

Also no log records are created in application or exception log, pdf is not protected and I'm sure that the folder is writable.
All help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: +1 for reminding me about `new pdf()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just forgot to pass along the `destination`

```
pdf.thumbnail(destination=arguments.destination
          , pages = arguments.pages
          , resolution = arguments.resolution
          , scale = arguments.scale
          , overwrite = arguments.overwrite);
```

Comment: You're right. Fixed everything. Thanks! How could i missed that. Probably means that i should get some sleep.